# How do you set up a grid for X number of images with captions as links using grid and flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists, css-grid

I'm trying to reproduce the functionality here on this page, which I've bunked together using the BigCommerce engine. It loads pretty horrifically slow. Page in question:

https://idealcalibrations.com/portable-gas-detectors-info/

I've been reading and to the best of my understanding I should be using CSS grid to solve this problem, but I'm a bit hopeless with CSS/HTML aside from following guides. I'd like to speed this page up and load it properly. Essentially it is a collection of the links here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRPMR.jpg)

I have an image and a caption (the name of the instrument in the photo), both of which I'd like to link to a URL.

If anyone has an idea they could help me out with I'd greatly appreciate it. Small business owner trying to figure out the web over here

Thanks,

James

I've tried organizing the page using tables, but everything I'm reading is saying I'm doing it wrong and the pages don't render well on mobile. It looks like the solution is something to do with ULs and LIs but I'm not sure how to make it interpret those for the grid to load, especially not with images and the text below needing to be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML grid system nicely organizes columns and rows on a page, and css media queries can be used to redistribute and size columns, rows, amd images within the grid.

```css
html {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.products {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both
}

.display {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.pic {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

figcaption {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  <div class="products">
    <figure>
      <a href="#.png" target="blank"><img src="https://praestocreative.com/images/pic1.png" class="pic" alt="pic"></a>
      <figcaption><a href="#.png">Picture 1</a></figcaption>
     </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="products">
    <figure>
      <a href="#.png" target="blank"><img src="https://praestocreative.com/images/pic2.png" class="pic" alt="pic"></a>
      <figcaption><a href="#.png">Picture 2</a></figcaption>
      </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="products">
    <figure>
      <a href="#.png" target="blank"><img src="https://praestocreative.com/images/pic3.png" class="pic" alt="pic"></a>
      <figcaption><a href="#.png">Picture 3</a></figcaption>
      </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="products">FOUR</div>
  <div class="products">FIVE</div>
  <div class="products">SIX</div>
  <div class="products">SEVEN</div>
  <div class="products">EIGHT</div>
  <div class="products">NINE</div>
  <div class="products">TEN</div>
  <div class="products">ELEVEN</div>
  <div class="products">TWELVE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay, working on it now.

Comment: I clearly have to slow down...too much Peets coffee! Edits made...I'll be more careful.

Comment: Worked great, thanks I can take it from here, really appreciate it.